# Ngx-Bootstrap Typeahead retaining dropdown values of last entered character on input clear when used with http calls

Tags: angular, rxjs, typeahead, ngx-bootstrap

Ngx-bootstrap not working as expected when I clear the input quickly as it retains the values of the last entered character.
For Example: If I type "a" quickly and remove it before the HTTP call is resolved, it retains the list of values for "a" in the typeahead even when input is empty.
This is easily replicable in its documentation https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/typeahead?tab=overview#async-http-request.

[image: screenshot from above link]

Can anybody help with a workaround??

Comment: Did you see the `typeaheadWaitMs` option documented below the example in the page that you linked?

Comment: Yes, it's replicable in that example too.